# Function in a SQL query. Is it possible?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

So, in the previous question I asked, [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49560499/why-does-wpdb-get-result-return-value-different-from-the-get-posts-from-ad)

and didn't get any answer, so I have an idea from the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49560499/why-does-wpdb-get-result-return-value-different-from-the-get-posts-from-ad) of mine, to make it more compact, so this what I thought, is it possible to call a function in a SQL query?

So this is the condition I had now, I have a function to convert price using API, and I want to sort it by price but the problem is each product have different currency.

**Ex:**

> Product A - USD 1,800
>
> Product B - IDR 1,900,000
>
> Product C - EUR 1,000

So if I just sort by the price from the database, it'll messed up, because the currency are different. So I want to make the all the data from mysql is automatically changed to price in USD (default, here is when the function needed)

```
$args=array(
    'meta_key'      => 'monthly',
    'meta_value'    => 'yes',
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'paged' => $paged
);

$mam_global_fields = ', price.meta_value'; // I want to change this 
$mam_global_join = " 
    INNER JOIN " . $wpdb->postmeta . " AS currency ON (" . $wpdb->posts . ".ID = currency.post_id AND currency.meta_key = 'monthly_currency')
    INNER JOIN " . $wpdb->postmeta . " AS price ON (" . $wpdb->posts . ".ID = price.post_id AND price.meta_key = 'monthly_price')
";
mam_global_orderby="total_price ASC";
```

**...To something like this, but I don't know how to do this, but it's something like this or some way similar like this or my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49560499/why-does-wpdb-get-result-return-value-different-from-the-get-posts-from-ad)**

```
$mam_global_fields = ', price.meta_value, '. convert_price('price.meta_value', 'currency.meta_value') . ' AS total_price';
```

I appreciate any kind of helps or ideas

Comment: You can't inject a PHP function into an SQL query, no.

Comment: Just get them and use PHP's `usort` function to do the sorting part.

Comment: You can use a stored procedure, or maybe a trigger if you want to save it.  Personally I dislike both as they give to much responsibility to the DB layer, but that is my opinion, and it's more of a guidline for me then a rule.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I see, so it's clearly impossible. But if I use it from the PHP side, the sql still showing the wrong the product then

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix but I think I still can't get all the price in USD right?

Comment: That's unfortunately the problem you face when you store different kinds of data and expect to compare them. You should consider storing a "normalised" price, which could be the "most recently calculated" USD value. Have a `cron` script run every so often to update them, since exchange rates vary.

Comment: sorry, **you can do it**. You can write a very small piece of C-code to write a User-Function **(UDF)**. That you can call like every other implemented MySql function. see : https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/data/mfc_database/misc/article.php/c12615/MySQL-UDFs.htm

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol yeah I know it's a problematic situation. I already thought about store the latest price in database, then use it if the API is dead. but I still confuse for using wordpress, I know how to done it on native PHP or PHP framework, but in wordpress. I'm blind, especially this website is already running for 5 years I think(?) and this wordpress version is very old, and when I tried to update the wordpress all the code inside are messed up, so I rolled it back to the original.

Comment: Sounds like you may need to re-write the code to something more manageable. It's a daunting task but it will save you a *lot* of trouble long-term.

Comment: @BerndBuffen **Really? I can?** never heard about this **(UDF)** function, I will learn how it work first then. Thank you !

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - that's what I call a sticky wicket.  Is it more trouble to fix it up front or to deal with it over and over.  That's what it boils down to.  A procedural function, is basically a query you store in the DB and then can run by using `$sql = "Call {procedure}"` or such, I forget how to call them haven't used them in some time.  A trigger is a stored query that executes automatically when something happens in the DB.  I haven't used them sense they put FULL TEXT in Innodb, back in the day you could emulate cascade deletes and updates in MyISAM tables

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Yeah I think I should do it, the code were messed up and have some much error of deprecated PHP function. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Khrisna Gunanasurya - i have done it often, to calculate some things or call Web / Rest APIs. I will look for a better tutorial ("hello World"), but i cant found it in this moment. Note the UDF-Interface ist not 100% compatible between MySQL and MariaDB. So look at the correct Doku

Comment: @Khrisna Gunanasurya - 
 Here the MySQL Doku: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/adding-udf.html

Comment: The other thing to consider if it's an out of date version of wordpress is there are some security concerns involved with not updating wordpress.  Some not insignificant ones.

Comment: @BerndBuffen I found this UDF function is very interesting, OK noted, thanks for the help !

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix That's the problem, I want to update the wordpress version but there are so many plugins that didn't compatible with the latest version, and especially the custom code from the custom themes all deprecated

Comment: That is actually my specialty, you just have to work though it.  Security is nothing to fool around with.  I just recently fixed a site running on WP 2.7... it was chuck full of malware too.  I put so many `Deny from all` htaccess files in there Houdini couldn't get in if he wanted to ... lol  ... They (the bad guys) were just executing PHP right though the url query string too, wasn't cool.

Comment: i recommend a local store of the currencies (SOURCE_CURRENCY, DEST_CURRENCY, CURRENCY_DATE, EXCHANGE_RATE)...so you dont make the same call for the same source currency/dest currency and date...because 1. performance and 2. companies charge for the number of calls you do...3. if you do too many...you get denial of service error...only make the call if the row doesnt exist in your local store

Comment: @Ctznkane525 yeah you got a point, I already thinking about store it on database instead so the table will be updated hourly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use `CASE`?

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fd178a/15/0

Example:

```
SELECT id, name, CASE currency
  WHEN "USD" THEN price * 1.1
  WHEN "RUB" THEN price * 0.7
  WHEN "CND" THEN price * 2.8
END as price
FROM book
ORDER BY price DESC
```

Where `1.1`, `0.7` and `2.8` are base coeffs for convertions in base / main currency.

**UPDATE**

... or you can use MySQL JSON type to create something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE book (id INT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(60), price REAL, currency VARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO book VALUES (1, "book 1", 1.20, "USD");
INSERT INTO book VALUES (2, "book 2", 100.0, "CND");
INSERT INTO book VALUES (3, "book 3", 12.20, "RUB");

SET @currency := '{"CND": 0.8, "RUB": 1.7, "JPN": 0.34, "USD": 1.0}';

SELECT id, name, JSON_EXTRACT(@currency, CONCAT('$.', currency)) * price as price
FROM book
ORDER BY price DESC;
```

SQLFiddle: http://rextester.com/JNLNE4909

Comment: Ahhh I got your point, so I just need to make the price is checked before the SQL, thanks! It's more simple then using a stored procedure I think

Answer (score 1):

You can use stored function, this function can take currency type and value as input parameter, and return usd value. Then you can call this function in your sql query where you need.

Comment: I will really appreciate it if you really willing to write me the function

Comment: @KhrisnaGunanasurya-

The link below gives sql query for currency conversion.Lot of sql works needs to be done 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39882140/sql-currency-conversion-from-given-currency-to-destination-currency

Comment: krishna, you will thank us someday IF YOU WRITE your own function. just do it.

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ well I don't asking for someone to write the code, it's him the one that offering to write the function for me. Like I said, `I appreciate any kind of helps or ideas`. So if someone wants to write the codes for me, of course I'll appreciate it.

Comment: well he gives you the link to start it. what are you waiting for? we do this for free so that person is already kind enough to lead you to right direction.

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ Well I don't waiting for anybody, did I say I waiting for somebody to create the code for me? can you just see the comments on my question? :) `FYI: I already create the code, it's not hurt to have somebody write some code for you, so you can see if you lack on some points or someone can write the code more clean or compact than me`

Comment: thn why you keep arguing if you have started doing it? just do it. you will LOVE it!!!

Comment: I have seen that you tagged mysql. I work with oracle sql and write stored procedures in pl/sql. I don worked with mysql.